# How do I exclude rows that count returns 0 for sql subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, sccm

I am working on an Update Compliance Report using System Center Data. I have the query I want but I cannot remove the rows that have a 0 count for Failed Update, or my Required/Deployed Updates.

I have played with HAVING but only got it to return NULLS and still could not exclude them.

```
select distinct
rs.name0 as 'Computer Name',
rs.description0 AS 'Description',
os.Caption0 as 'Operating System',
case 
      when CS.ClientActiveStatus='1' then 'Active' 
      when CS.ClientActiveStatus='0' then 'Inactive'
end
      as 'Client Active Status',

--Last Hardware Scan
convert(varchar(26), ws.lasthwscan, 100) as 'Last Hardware Scan',

--Last Software Scan (Convert to EST)
convert(varchar(26), (dateadd(hour, -4, uss.LastScanTime)), 100) as 'Last Software Scan',

--Required/Deployed Updates
(select count(ucs.ResourceID)
from v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
    join v_updateinfo ui on ui.ci_id=ucs.ci_id
    join V_CITargetedMachines ctm on ctm.ci_id=ucs.ci_id and ctm.ResourceID = ucs.ResourceID
where ucs.resourceid=rs.ResourceID and ucs.Status='2' and ui.LocaleID='9' and ui.IsDeployed='1' and ui.IsSuperseded='0'
) as 'Required/Deployed Updates',

--Failed Updates
(select count(ucs.ResourceID)
from v_UpdateComplianceStatus ucs
    join v_UpdateInfo ui on ucs.ci_id=ui.ci_id and ucs.Status='2'  and ui.LocaleID='9' and ui.IsDeployed='1' and ui.IsSuperseded='0' and ucs.LastEnforcementMessageID In (6,11,14)
    join v_StateNames sn on ucs.LastEnforcementMessageID = sn.StateID and sn.TopicType=402
where ucs.resourceid=rs.ResourceID
) as 'Failed Updates',

--Reboot Check
(select iif(sum(iif(ucs.LastEnforcementMessageID='9',1,0)) > 0,'Yes','No')
from v_UpdateComplianceStatus ucs
where ucs.resourceid=rs.ResourceID
) as 'Reboot Required'

from v_R_System rs
    join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM os on rs.ResourceID=os.ResourceID
    join v_FullCollectionMembership fcm on rs.ResourceID=fcm.ResourceID
    join v_Collection col on fcm.CollectionID=col.CollectionID
    Join v_CH_ClientSummary CS on rs.ResourceId=CS.ResourceID
    join v_GS_WORKSTATION_STATUS ws on rs.ResourceID=ws.ResourceID
    join v_UpdateScanStatus uss on rs.ResourceID=uss.ResourceID

where 'Required/Deployed Updates' > '0' and 'Failed Updates' > '0'
order by rs.Name0 asc
```

I would like if Required/Deployed Updates or Failed Updates count is 0 to be excluded.

Currently Getting

```
Computer Name | Description | Operating System | Client Active Status | Last Hardware Scan | Last Software Scan | Required/Deployed Updates | Failed Updates | Reboot Required
WKS1 | Test Laptop 1 | Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise | Active | Apr 5 2019 12:00PM | Apr 5 2019 12:00PM | 0 | 0 | No
WKS2 | Test Laptop 2 | Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise | Active | Apr 2 2019 12:46PM | Apr 5 2019 12:02PM | 0 | 0 | Yes
WKS3 | Test Laptop 3 | Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise | Active | Apr 2 2019 12:46PM | Apr 5 2019 12:02PM | 1 | 1 | Yes
```

Would like to get

```
Computer Name | Description | Operating System | Client Active Status | Last Hardware Scan | Last Software Scan | Required/Deployed Updates | Failed Updates | Reboot Required
WKS3 | Test Laptop 3 | Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise | Active | Apr 2 2019 12:46PM | Apr 5 2019 12:02PM | 1 | 1 | Yes
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in the `WHERE` clause.

You can wrap another `SELECT` around yours and apply the conditions on the aliased expression there.

```
SELECT ...
       FROM (SELECT ...,
                    (SELECT count(...)
                            FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
                            ...) "Required/Deployed Updates"
                    (SELECT count(...)
                            FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
                            ...) "Failed Updates",
                    FROM ...
                    WHERE ...) x
       WHERE "Required/Deployed Updates" > 0
             AND "Failed Updates" > 0;
```

Or you can simply repeat the expression, in your case the subselects.

```
SELECT ...
      (SELECT count(...)
              FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
              ...) "Required/Deployed Updates",
      (SELECT count(...)
              FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
              ...) "Failed Updates"
      ...
      FROM ...
      WHERE ...
            AND (SELECT count(...)
                        FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
                        ...) > 0
            AND (SELECT count(...)
                        FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
                        ...) > 0
      ...
```

In your case, since you want to check for a count of rows of a table not being zero, i.e. if a row exists, you could also use `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause, which might speed things up a little.

```
SELECT ...
      (SELECT count(...)
              FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
              ...) "Required/Deployed Updates",
      (SELECT count(...)
              FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
              ...) "Failed Updates"
      ...
      FROM ...
      WHERE ...
            AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM v_update_compliancestatus ucs
                               ...)
            AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM 
                               v_update_compliancestatus ucs)
      ...
```

Also note, that you don't need to wrap numeric literals in single quotes (`'`. And don't wrap aliases in single quotes either, use double quotes (`"`) if you want or need to quote an alias. In SQL Server you can also use brackets like in `[alias]`.

Comment: Thanks, Sticky Bit. I will try this today and get back with you. :)